# Using regex with like clause with Sybase DB

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

When I hit the follwing query I get 1 row

```
SELECT * FROM servers WHERE Node='abc_deeh32q6610007'
```

However when I hit the following query 0 rows are selected

```
SELECT * FROM servers WHERE Node LIKE '%_deeh32q6610007'
```

I thought it may be because of `_` but the same pattern seen whhen I use the following queries

```
SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE TicketNumber like '%979415' --> returns 0 rows
SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE TicketNumber='IN979415' --> returns 1 row
```

I am using Sybase DB.

Comment: Weird. What is the type of `TicketNumber`?

Comment: Both TicketNumber and Node are of type `2` That's what I see when I do `describe alerts` and `describe servers` from the console.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of errors should not appear in a healthy database.

First check if maybe the characters are correct and you are using a correct *%* character code. Write a script in plan text and check it with *isql* using *-i* option run directly from command line.

If that won't help and your problem persists then probably you have some problems with the physical structures of the database:

- Check if you have properly configured the sort order in the database: you can reload the character set order using the *charset* tool.
- Check if you have no errors in the database structure: run *dbcc checkdb* and *dbcc checkalloc* to see if there are no physical errors in the data
- Check if your don't have any errors in the database error log. All physical errors observed by the database should be logged here.

If that won't help try to reproduce the same problem in another table with copy of the data. Then on an another server with the same configuration. Try to narrow the problem.